# Cakephp 3 create i18n table in phpmyadmin issue

Tags: mysql, cakephp, indexing, internationalization, cakephp-3.x

I have a problem to create i18n table for CakePHP 3 Translate Behavior. So I have my database in phpmyadmin and when I want to execute this piece of code from the official cookbook :

```
CREATE TABLE i18n (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    locale varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    foreign_key int(10) NOT NULL,
    field varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX I18N_LOCALE_FIELD(locale, model, foreign_key, field),
    INDEX I18N_FIELD(model, foreign_key, field)
);
```

PhpMyAdmin say :

## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I'm in uft8_unicode_ci. Should I go for utf8_general_ci?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 5 workarounds for the dreaded 767 problem:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in size requirements between `utf8_unicode` and `utf8_general`, they only differ with regards to sorting.

By default the index (key prefix) limit is 767 bytes for InnoDB tables (and 1000 bytes for MyISAM), if applicable enable the `innodb_large_prefix` option (it is enabled by default as of MySQL 5.7) which raises the limit to 3072 bytes, or make the `VARCHAR` columns smaller, and/or change their collation, the `locale` column (which holds ISO locale/country codes) surely doesn't use unicode characters, and chances are that your model and column/field names also only use ASCII characters, and that their names are way below 255 characters in length.

With an ASCII collation the `VARCHAR` columns require only 1 byte per char, unlike with UTF-8, which can require up to 3 bytes (or 4 bytes for the `mb4` variants), which alone already causes the index size limit to be exceeded (3 * 255 * 2 = 1530).

See also

- **[MySQL 5.7 Manual > Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-charsets.html)**
- **[MySQL 5.7 Manual > Limits on InnoDB Tables > Maximums and Minimums](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html#innodb-mximums-minimums)**
- **[MySQL 5.7 Manual > InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables > innodb_large_prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix)**

Answer (score 0):

I have limited my request with :

model varchar(85) NOT NULL,
field varchar(85) NOT NULL,

model and field at 85, I think it's enought, I mysql accept it.

Hope that will help someone.

Comment: Good that it works for you. Please note that you should accept answers that solved the problem, so that questions appear resolved for future readers, which is especially imporant when people search for answers! I'd advise that you revisit your previous questions too, and mark the correct answers as accepted.